# How to work out if two different selectors point to the same element on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom, playwright

Given the following page

```html
<div id="something">
    <div id="selected">
    </div>
</div>
```

In playwright I have two selectors like this..

```js
selectorA = "#something >> div >> nth=1";
selectorB = "#selected";
```

These two selectors point to the same element on the page. How can I compare the two selectors / locators to figure out if they are pointing to the same element or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it.

```
async function compareLocators(firstLocator: Locator, secondLocator: Locator): Promise<boolean> {
    const firstHandle = await firstLocator.elementHandle();
    const secondHandle = await secondLocator.elementHandle();
    return firstLocator.page().evaluate(
        compare => compare.left.isEqualNode(compare.right),
        { left: firstHandle, right: secondHandle }
    );
}
```

Now you can feed this function two locators and it returns true/false if they point to the same locator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [playwright inspector](https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#debugging-selectors)

https://playwright.dev/docs/debug#debugging-selectors

Comment: The inspector will not do what I need in the test.  What I am looking for is a solution I can use in code to work out if one locator found using 'selectorA' is the same as another locator found using the other 'selectorB'.

I know they are the same as you can see from my little example page!.

Comment: oh, it is an interesting question, you can try this little library https://github.com/alexferrari88/playwright-DOMPath. In theory what you can do is : await cssPath(await page.$(“first_selector”))  and compare result with second one.

Comment: So far this library is the best way of working out if the two locators are the same

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve both with `document.querySelector` and compare the two object, if it is the same element, they will reference the same one.

```
document.querySelector(selectorA) === document.querySelector(selectorB)
```

Comment: This solution (if it works) is not ideal. The code of playwright does not execute within the browser context so simply doing the above is not that simple.

Comment: It works if you do it like this:

```
            const matchSameElement = await pageContext.pwPage.evaluate(
                ([a, b]) =>
                    document.querySelector(a) === document.querySelector(b),
                [selectorA, selectorB]
            );

            await expect(matchSameElement).toBeTruthy();
```